# Выбрать id всех товаров и для каждого из них создать строку следующего вида id.doc

Tags: jquery

Выбрать id всех товаров и для каждого из них создать строку следующего вида "id.doc",например "1.doc" .Добавьте для каждого выбранного href элемента "<a>" с классом "document" врезультате чего должно быть например <a href="1.doc">1</a> <a href="2.doc">2</a>

```
<html>
<table id='orders' border='1'>
<thead>
<tr>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>Товар</th>
  <th>Цена</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>AAA</td>
   <td>30p</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>BBB</td>
    <td>50p</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>CCC</td>
    <td>50p</td>  
   </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  </html>
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("td:first-child").before('<a href="#"></a>'); //туть нужно исправить 
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: Задание вообще не понял, вы такую кашу написали...

Comment: выбираеш колонку id и делаеш этот элемент сылкой например <a href="1.doc">1</a>  <a href="2.doc">2</a> и тд

Comment: @cheburashkarf, если дан правильный ответ, то поставьте галочку слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#orders tbody tr").each(function() {
            var link = "http://site.ru/" + $(this).children('td').eq(0).text() + ".doc";
            var text = $(this).children('td').eq(0).html();
            $(this).children('td').eq(0).html("<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + text + "</a>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: .

    $(this).children('td').eq(0).html("<a href=\"" + link + "\">" + text + "</a>");

=>

    $(this).children('td').eq(0).html($('<a>', {'href': link, 'html': text}));